# Updating subarray property with MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose and MongoDB, and I'm trying to update the values of the following model :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username  : String,
  playlist  : [{
    name    : String,
    active  : {type: Boolean, default: false},
  }]
});
```

What I want to do is to set all the playlists of one user to false, then set only one to true. And by doing the following request, it happens to erase the informations in my playlists :

```
this.model('User').findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {$set:{playlist:{active:false}}})
  .exec(
    function(err, user){
      //DO callback treatment here
    });
```

I have seen some people saying that once they retrieved the User, they had to do a foreach on the subarray, but is there no way to use directly mongoose and mongodb to do such a treatment ?

Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{$set: {'playlist.$.active': false}
```

Read about it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick !  
I had to specify the playlist to update and then specifying the field with the positionnal operator it worked :  

`this.model('User').update({_id:userId, 'playlist.active':true},{$set:{"playlist.$.active":false}})
    .exec(
      function(err, user){
        //CODE MANAGEMENT HERE
      });`

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```
{$set:{playlist:{active:false}}}
```

Then you're replacing the *whole* `playlist` array as you `$set` the `playlist` argument. You should be able to do the following to just add an extra field to `playlist`:

```
{$set:{"playlist.active": false}}
```

Here you're not modifying the `playlist` argument, but instead just instruct MongoDB to do something with the `active` field in `playlist`.